# No me funciona el atributo disabled con el select

Tags: javascript, select

He probado varias formas de activar y desactivar un select. Sin embargo, solo consigo desactivarlos pero no activarlos. El código es muy sencillo, al presionar un botón se activa una función en Javascript que habilita varios campos entre los cuales está dos select.

Aquí va el código HTML

```
    <div class="form-group col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <label>Nacionalidad (*)</label>
    <select id="nacionalidad" name="nacionalidad" class="form-control selectpicker" data- 
   live-search="true" required disabled="TRUE">
    <option value="VENEZUELA" selected>VENEZUELA</option>
    <option value="COLOMBIA">COLOMBIA</option>
    <option value="PERÚ">PERÚ</option>
    <option value="BRASIL">BRASIL</option>
    <option value="ARGENTINA">ARGENTINA</option>
    <option value="CHILE">CHILE</option>
    <option value="EEUU">EEUU</option>
    <option value="OTRO">OTRO</option>
    </select>
    </div>
```

El código en Javascript

```
    function editarform()
    {
    //$('#nacionalidad').removeAttr("disabled");
    //$('#tipo_doc').prop('disabled',false);
    //document.getElementById('nacionalidad').disabled=false;
    document.getElementById('nacionalidad').removeAttribute('disabled');
    }
```

Cuando presiono el botón no activa los select...alguien me podrá dar una manito???

Comment: Prueba con `document.getElementById('nacionalidad').removeAttribute('disabled')`  https://jsfiddle.net/e8rncfy0/

Comment: tu selec se llama nacionalidad y estas desabilitando tipo_doc

Answer (score 1):

tu select se llama nacionalidad y estas deshabilitando tipo_doc

así seria:

```js
    function editarform()
    {
    if(document.getElementById('nacionalidad').disabled){
    document.getElementById('nacionalidad').disabled=false;
    }else{
    document.getElementById('nacionalidad').disabled=true;
    }
    }
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
    <label>Nacionalidad (*)</label>
    <select id="nacionalidad" name="nacionalidad" class="form-control selectpicker" data- 
   live-search="true" required disabled="TRUE">
    <option value="VENEZUELA" selected>VENEZUELA</option>
    <option value="COLOMBIA">COLOMBIA</option>
    <option value="PERÚ">PERÚ</option>
    <option value="BRASIL">BRASIL</option>
    <option value="ARGENTINA">ARGENTINA</option>
    <option value="CHILE">CHILE</option>
    <option value="EEUU">EEUU</option>
    <option value="OTRO">OTRO</option>
    </select>
    </div>
    
    <button onClick="editarform()">activar</button>
```

Comment: Me pasa algo raro, solo me funciona un una función javascrip, pero cuando la coloco en otra función ya no funciona.  No he podido solucionarlo hasta ahora.  Sin embargo, agradezco sus buenas colaboraciones.